# Problem with Composer and Zend with development mode

Tags: xampp, composer-php, zend-framework3

- Apache: XAMPP
- PHP Version: 7.2
- Framework: Zend Framework 3

When I try to use `composer development-enable` in VSC Console it shows me:

```
<strong>"'zf-development-mode' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
Script zf-development-mode status handling the development-status event returned with error code 1"</strong>
```

I tried a few tips from Google but I still need help

Comment: Do you have the same problem when you run the command in your terminal? What is the exact command being executed how do you call it in VS Code?

Comment: What did you do to install ZF3? Also, this error has nothing to do with VSC (the bit `composer` was recognized, so `composer` is part of the Windows PATH Environment variable). - Did you follow any tutorials? Did you run `composer install` before you tried `composer development-enable`?